# Is incrementing Py_True/Py_False refcount always necessary?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm new to the Python C-API and browsing through some source code to pick parts of it up.

Here is a minimal version of a function that I found, in the C source of a package that contains extension modules:

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
modulename_myfunc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {

    // Call PyArg_ParseTuple, etc ...

    // Dummy values; in the real function they are calculated
    int is_found = 1;
    Py_ssize_t n_bytes_found = 1024;

    PyObject *result;
    result = Py_BuildValue("(Oi)",
                           is_found ? Py_True : Py_False,  // Py_INCREF?
                           n_bytes_found);
    return result;
}
```

**Does this introduce a small memory leak by failing to use `Py_INCREF` on either `Py_True` or `Py_False`?**  The C-API [docs for Boolean object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bool.html) seem pretty explicit about always needing to incref/decref `Py_True` and `Py_False`.

If a `Py_INCREF` does need to be introduced, how can it most properly be used here, assuming that `Py_RETURN_TRUE`/`Py_RETURN_FALSE` aren't really applicable because a tuple is being returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason a `Py_INCREF` is not used here is because [`Py_BuildValue`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue), when being passed an object with "O" will increment the reference count for you:

> O (object) [PyObject *]
>
> Pass a Python object untouched (except for its reference count, which is incremented by one). If the object passed in is a NULL pointer, it is assumed that this was caused because the call producing the argument found an error and set an exception. Therefore, Py_BuildValue() will return NULL but won’t raise an exception. If no exception has been raised yet, SystemError is set.

You'll see a similar usage here in CPython [itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/526a01467b3277f9fcf7f91e66c23321caa1245d/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L1063) for example.